# Small Problems with Bubble Sort Method

Tags: c, malloc

My visual studio always trows different exepctions.(Bubble sort.exe has triggered a breakpoint.)
sometimes on line 6 :(arr_2 = (int *)malloc(size);
Sometimes on lines where is free (arr) and free(arr_2);

```
int bubble(int size, int * arr) {
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("array[%d] = %d \n", i, arr[i]);
}
int * arr_2;
arr_2 = (int *)malloc(size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr_2[i] = arr[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("2array_2[%d] = %d \n", i, arr_2[i]);
}
int numb;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {                                               
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        numb = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = numb;
    }

}
free(arr_2);
return 0;
};
int main(){
char size[100];
printf("Hello! Please enter the size of the array that will be sorted with 
bubble sort method \n Maximum size is 100 \n");
gets_s(size);
int size_1 = atoi(size);
int * arr;
arr = (int *)malloc(size_1);
for (int i = 0; i < size_1; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand();
}
bubble(size_1, arr);


free(arr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your title to better describe your problem. You additionally do not need to list the language (it's covered by the tags), and it doesn't need to be all uppercase. Editing your code to fix the indentation will additionally help readers.

Comment: this is either c, or c++ trying very hard to look like c. why are you using `malloc` and `free` ?

Comment: I think you need a read of this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

The error with malloc will be easy to see when you put a breakpoint there

Comment: i find it a bit sad that c++ has to argue against using c stuff so often. I dont know any c, but I am pretty sure it is a language almost as beautiful as c++, there is just no valid reason to use `malloc` and `free` in your code if it is c++

Comment: If you have problems with `malloc()` and `free()`, you don't have _small_ problems, you have BIG problems. Storage management is one of the most terrible things for entry-level programmers (and the others as well). As this is tagged C++, why not `std::vector`? It makes things much easier (no `malloc()`/`free()` nor `new[]`/`delete[]` needed).

Comment: Concerning C++ and `std::vector`, have a look at this: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a74605180fc405d). As I told you: no `malloc()`/`free()` nor `new[]`/`delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Usу something like this:

```
int bubble(int size, int * arr)
{
    int numb;
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        for(int j = 0;j < size - i - 1; j++)
            if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                numb = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = numb;
            }

    return 0;
};


// using
int main()
{
    char size[100];
    printf("Hello! Please enter the size of the array that will be sorted with bubble sort method \n Maximum size is 100 \n");
    gets_s(size);
    int size_1 = atoi(size);

    int * arr = new int[size_1];

    for(int i = 0; i < size_1; i++)
        arr[i] = rand();
    bubble(size_1, arr);
    delete []arr;
}
```

You don't need a copy of your input array.

Answer (score 0):

When you reserve memory with malloc you should convert to size in bytes.
Use malloc( number_of_elements * sizeof( element ) ).

```
int size_1 = atoi(size);
int * arr;
arr = (int *)malloc(size_1 * sizeof( int ) );
for (int i = 0; i < size_1; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand();
}
```